# Replicate SQL chages to Database DEFINITION

Tags: sql, database, macros, record

Suppose I have two identical DataBases A and B, but with different Data. The tables, store procedures, etc are originally the same in both.

Now I start doing changes in the definition of DataBase A,  like adding a new Table, deleting a Column of another table, after I finish all these changes , I would like to have "recorded" these changes to rerun them in DataBase B, so DataBase B definition will continue to be the same as DataBase A (the Data in both of them will still be different from A to B).

How can I record changes made in A and rerun them in B? Note that the changes I'm talking about are not in the Data but in the DataBase definition.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? But in general you should be doing it that way: You should put all your changes into SQL scripts that are then applied to the database. Thus you can migrate any database to any version. Check out Liquibase or Flyway for tools helping you with that. Never ever change the database "manually".

Comment: Agree with Mr Horse despite all the IDE assists for this sort of thing. I always write a sql script and then run it. In my experience you always regret not having it written down somewhere.